# Abelian normal subgroup with a prescribed index. Problem 1.G.4 from M.Isaacs FGT

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

I try to solve the problem with a number **1.G.4** from M.Isaacs book (one can see it [here](https://books.google.ru/books?id=pCLhYaMUg8IC&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=abelian%20subgroup%20of%20nonabelian%20group%20Chermak%20Delgado&source=bl&ots=3pLLSmr4HA&sig=W1Me1lDSmqy5Hlkah1VMPj_wNMU&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjywsrMhaDYAhWiF5oKHV1IA74Q6AEISTAE#v=onepage&q=abelian%20subgroup%20of%20nonabelian%20group%20Chermak%20Delgado&f=false)). I will give this problem.

> Let $G$ be a nonabelian group and  $A\subset G$ be an abelian subgroup
>   of $G$. Show that there exists a **normal abelian** subgroup $N$ of $G$
>   such that $|G:N|<|G:A|^2$.

It is an immediate consequence of the problem **1.G.1** (see [here](https://books.google.ru/books?id=pCLhYaMUg8IC&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=abelian%20subgroup%20of%20nonabelian%20group%20Chermak%20Delgado&source=bl&ots=3pLLSmr4HA&sig=W1Me1lDSmqy5Hlkah1VMPj_wNMU&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjywsrMhaDYAhWiF5oKHV1IA74Q6AEISTAE#v=onepage&q=abelian%20subgroup%20of%20nonabelian%20group%20Chermak%20Delgado&f=false)) that  the Chermak-Delgado measure of $A$ is maximal and
$$
Z(G)\subset A,\  A=C_G(A),\ |G:A|^2 = |G:Z(G)|.
$$

Now I try to construct $N\vartriangleleft
G$ such that 
$$
Z(G)\subsetneq N\vartriangleleft
A.$$
I thought about $\mathrm{core}_G(A)$, but my attempts did not lead to success.

Also there is a "solution" of this problem [here](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~bahra004/fgt.pdf). But there is incorrect argument there about the product of abelian groups: the product of (permutable but not necessary element-wise permutable) abelian groups  is abelian.

Comment: I haven't been able to solve 1G.1, help
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4693382/show-that-a-is-a-member-of-the-maximum-measure-lattice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If not, then by 1.G.1 we have $A \in \mathcal{L}(G)$, and so by
   1.G.2 there exists $M \unlhd G$ with $A \le M < G$.

   By the Chermak-Delgado Theorem, $M$ has a characteristic subgroup
   $N$ with $|M:N| \le |M:A|^2$, and then $N \unlhd G$ with
   $$|G:N|=|G:M||M:N| \le  |G:M||M:A|^2 < |G:M|^2|M:A|^2 = |G:A|^2.$$

Comment: Thank you very much, Derek! The only trick in this problem is to use Chermak-Delgado group twice...And what can you say about $core_G(A)$? Can this candidate to $N$ fail?

Comment: I don't know of any results concerning ${\rm core}_G(A)$, but I cannot at the moment think of an example where it fails.

Comment: Why is N normal?

Comment: @Juli $N\ {\rm char}\ M \unlhd G \Rightarrow N \unlhd G$.