# Show that A is a member of the maximum-measure lattice

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I've been working on Chermak-Delgado theory for a while now and I've had a hard time finding an answer to the exercises proposed by Martin Isaacs in his book finite group theory, so I'd like to share what I've thought so far, that way maybe we can reach an answer or work closer towards it.

Let $A \subseteq G$, where A is abelian, and assume that there does not exist
a characteristic abelian subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $|G : N| < |G : A|^2$. Show
that $A = C_G(A)$ is a member of the maximum-measure lattice $\mathfrak{L}(G)$ and
that $|G:Z(G)| = |G:A|^2$

The measure mentioned in the exercise is the Chermak-Delgado measure defined as follows:

Let $H \leq G$ with $G$ a group, then the Chermak-Delgado measure is $m_G(H)=|H| |C_G(H)|$ where $C_G(H)$ denotes the centralizer of $H$ in $G$, subgroups with maximum measure form a lattice $\mathfrak{L}(G)$.

So far, I've proved the maximum measure of an abelian group is $n^2$ if the order of the group is $n$, therefore $A \in \mathfrak{L}(G)$.

Also,
$|G:Z(G)| = {|G| \over |Z(G)|}$ and $|Z(G)| = {|G|^2 \over |C_{Z(G)}(G)|}={|G|^2 \over |G|} = |G|$ so ${|G| \over |Z(G)|} = 1$ then $|G:A|^2= {|G|^2 \over |A|^2}$ would also need to be 1, but I can't prove it. help.

I also figured,
$|A|^2 \geq |G||Z(G)| \geq |A||Z(G)|$ so $|A| \geq |Z(G)|$ and therefore ${1 \over|A|} \leq {1 \over|Z(G)|}$

I haven't been able to solve this or any of the other 3 exercises left in section 1G so I'd greatly appreciate any help, thought, appreciation, opinion, comment or anything that helps me solve this exercise as I'll try and tackle them one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof of Problem 1G.1. So, let $A \subseteq G$, $A$ abelian and assume that no characteristic abelian subgroup $C$ exists, with $|G:C| \lt |G:A|^2$. By Theorem 1.41, we know that there exists a characteristic abelian subgroup $N$ (the Chermak-Delgado subgroup) with $|G:N| \leq |G:A|^2$. This forces $|G:N|=|G:A|^2$, or equivalently $\color{blue}{|A|^2=|G||N|}$.

$N$ has the property that $m_G(N) \geq m_G(A)$. Hence $|N||C_G(N)| \geq |A||C_G(A)| \geq |A|^2$. The last inequality follows from $A$ being abelian, so $A \subseteq C_G(A)$. From the blue formula above, it follows that $|N||C_G(N)| \geq |G||N|$, which forces $G=C_G(N)$, that is $N \subseteq Z(G)$. Using Corollary 1.45, this implies $N=Z(G)$ and $m_G(N)=|N||G|=|A|^2.$

Finally, $|A|^2=m_G(N) \geq m_G(A)=|A||C_G(A)| \geq |A|^2$, whence $m_G(N)=m_G(A)$ and $A=C_G(A)$. That proves that $A \in \frak{L}$.

Comment: I understand $m_G(A)=|A|^2 \geq m_G(N)$ but why does the equality happen?

Comment: From the formula in the proof in the book of Isaacs (Proof of Theorem 1.41) you derive $m_G(N)=|A|^2$. But $|A|^2 \leq m_G(A)$ ($A$ is abelian, so $A \subseteq C_G(A)$!). But $m_G(N)$ is maximal w.r.t. the Chermak-Delgado measure, whence $m_G(A)=m_G(N)$.

Comment: sorry, I meant I don't understand why $m_G(A)=|A|^2$

Comment: I changed the proof a bit, hope everything is clear now, thanks.

Comment: @Juli, if you deem my answer the right one, please tick it as such, as is the normal practice here at Math Stack Exchange. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I'll probably use this on my thesis, I'll make sure to add a big thank you to you in there

Comment: Thank you, good luck with your thesis!